# Microstrategy - deciding the title of graphs in dashboards

Tags: graph, dashboard, microstrategy

Everytime I put a graph in a dashboard it sets the title to the name of the dataset (report).
I'd like to decide it by myself. I searched a solution but i could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Microstrategy desktop you can edit a graph (you can just double-click on it or click the edit icon), select the graph title and right-click, now you should have an option to Edit it.

Otherwise you can reach the section Titles and modify the Title.

[image]